# Match Select items values to their Descriptions with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

How do I change the values of a select list to match their descriptors.
For example on page load I would like this:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Turkey</option>
<option value="1">Chicken</option>
<option value="1">Duck</option>
</select>
```

to become this:

```
<select>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
<option value="Duck">Duck</option>
</select>
```

Solution should work with dynamic text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must select all the options using this jQuery Selector `$("option")`, then for [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) element affect its text to its value, using this:

```
$(this).val($(this).text());
```

Here is a code snippet demo:

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
$("option").each(function(){

$(this).val($(this).text());
console.log($(this).val());

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">Turkey</option>
<option value="1">Chicken</option>
<option value="1">Duck</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Match</button>
```

If you want to do it without pressing the button use the following script:

```
$("option").each(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you can change value to inner text via this row: `$(this).val($(this).text())`. And if you want do it for every `option`, you should select all `options` via `$("option")` and iterate through them using `.each()` method. Here is the example:

```js
$("option").each(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).text())
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">Turkey</option>
<option value="1">Chicken</option>
<option value="1">Duck</option>
</select>
```